# Load all files from folder and subfolders

Tags: r

I know about the `source()` in R. 
It takes a path and/or filename to load i.e. a function which is saved in another .R file. What I need is basically the same command, but it is supposed to load every .R file from one folder and its subfolders.

Is there a oneliner (some library) or would I have to write a loop 'n everything?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This might work

```
lapply(list.files(pattern = "[.]R$", recursive = TRUE), source)
```

Comment: this will also load the files that are not `R` files like `testRandom.txt`

Comment: chill guys. Its okay.

Comment: @DhawalKapil Sorry if sounded too harsh, but your comment  + downvote left me no choice. I hope we will be able to avoid such incidents in the future. G/L and keep up the good work!

Comment: I would set the pattern to `"(?i)[.]r$"` to ignore case in the extension, but that's a cosmetic issue

Comment: @Tensibai I woulod set the pattern as `"[.][rR]$"`

Answer (score 2):

In R help of the library, you can find the following:

```
   ## If you want to source() a bunch of files, something like
  ## the following may be useful:
   sourceDir <- function(path, trace = TRUE, ...) {
      for (nm in list.files(path, pattern = "[.][RrSsQq]$")) {
         if(trace) cat(nm,":")
               source(file.path(path, nm), ...)
         if(trace) cat("\n")
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use a simple recursive function like

```
sourceRecursive <- function(path = ".") {
  dirs <- list.dirs(path, recursive = FALSE)
  files <- list.files(path, pattern = "^.*[Rr]$", include.dirs = FALSE, full.names = TRUE)
  for (f in files)
    source(f)
  for (d in dirs)
    sourceRecursive(d)
}
```